# How to Connect to Sql Server running in Linux Docker Container from IIS running locally on Windows 11 machine

Tags: sql-server, docker, iis, linux-containers

We are running ASP.NET apps locally on our dev machines in IIS.  We'd like to run Sql Server in a Linux Container rather than installing it on our machines.

We have Sql Server Running and are able to connect to it via SSMS and create db schemas, etc.  However, when we attempt to add a New Login for a local user that we would typically associate with an IIS App Pool, it fails with the following error

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Create failed for Login 'DEV17\IISAppPool'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=16.100.47008.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Login&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Windows NT user or group 'DEV17\IISAppPool' not found. Check the name again. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15401)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-15401-database-engine-error

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

An odd thing is that when do "Check Names" in the search, it finds the name
[image: Check Names Result]

The User exists
[image: computer management view]

Is there a way for us to grant IIS App Pools access to Sql Server databases with Sql Server running in a Linux container on a Windows 11 machine?

Comment: I assume you're talking about the [`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) Docker image here. When you connect using SSMS are you actually using Windows authentication? Or are you connecting using `sa` credentials, which is SQL Logon authentication? Either way you need to create an appropriate [LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql) at the server level and then map it to an appropriate [USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql) at the database level.

Comment: I haven't used Linux containers, if you are using Windows authentication and can't connect to Active Directory from a Linux container, maybe you could consider running SQL Server inside a Windows container instead. Alternatively you could try using SQL Server Authentication, create SQL Server logins that are not associated with Windows users or groups, this may require changing your application code to use a different authentication method.

Comment: @YurongDai  I appreciate your ideas as they got me outside of the box I was thinking in.  I just explored using a Windows container, but I can't find one for Sql Server 2022 running on Windows 11.  I'm open to using sql Logins, but not sure how to adjust IIS.  Also, I don't want to make changes to prod code, so as not to install Sql Server locally.  If you have insights as to how I could accomplish this locally without needing to change  prod code, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I am currently only connecting with SSMS using SA creds via Sql  Auth.  That is the context for the issue described above.  I'm getting the errors when I attempt to create a Login based upon a user that the search finds.

Comment: Aside... SQL Server in Windows containers stopped being supported back in 2021 - so much so that Microsoft actually unpublished all of their Windows container images. Ref: [Update- Beta program for SQL Server on Windows container is suspended.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/update-beta-program-for-sql-server-on-windows-container-is/ba-p/2516639)

Comment: The `DEV17\IISAppPool` is a local user of the Windows machine that's acting as Docker host. It's not a valid user inside a Linux-based Docker container. Have you considered creating an SQL Logon instead and using that login's username+password in the application's connection string?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, you bring up a good point.  I need to look into why our docs say that The IISAppPool User needs to be associated with a Sql Login.  Thank you.

Comment: It's probably a policy so as to avoid specifying usernames and passwords in connection strings, and would be easier to follow when dealing with Windows-based SQL Servers (just make sure all machines are members of the same authentication domain, configure the application pool to use a domain account, create a matching LOGIN and USER in SQL Server). If you need to follow it with Linux-based Docker containers you'll need to look into joining the containers to the domain using Kerberos.